# How to add bookmark to PDFs with Adobe Reader on Android

Tags: android, pdf

I know related questions have been asked, but this one seems hasn't been answered.

Is it possible to "add Bookmark"  with the Adobe Reader SDK for Android ? I have looked at the existing PDF apps on Google Play and none seem to have the obvious feature to "add a bookmark" to a  PDF, so is it possible at all? (A code snippet instead of a "see this  URL" answer would be appreciated).

The information at
https://www.adobe.com/devnet/readermobile.htm
doesn't seem that helpful in explaining how to go about this. Where is this API's  *documentation* ?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the answer you want to hear, but... you can't. Adobe Reader for Android does not provide an API beyond the intent-filter, so all it can do is display the PDF.

That said, there are open-source (and GPL) solutions out there which allow you to bookmark documents -- and then store those bookmarks locally.

Comment: Not quite the same, Alain. The OP wants to bookmark pages within a PDF document. ES File Explorer can't do that.

Comment: What's the "intent-filter"? I know that a PDF can be edited insofar as highlighting or annotation. What's the diference between bookmarking a PDF and bookmarking a document locally?